# Logic error when setting up user login attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, passwords

My asp.net application uses a customized logic for user login function. One of the requirements is that a user (once locked out) cannot gain access untill 15 minutes later.

My current logic is:

```
// check if account is locked & LastLoginAttempt is NOT over 15 minutes;
if ((iLoginAttempts > 4) && ( dtCurrentTimePlus15 < dtLastLoginAttempt))
{
    oCust.CustLoginStatus = "Your account is currently locked.";
    return false;
}
```

however, when the iLoginAttempts = 5 and dtLastLoginAttempt is 2 minutes ago.... why does the logic above skip the if clause?

Comment: What is in `dtCurrentTimePlus15`? Anyway it should be other way around: you should add 15 minutes to `dtLastLoginAttempt` and then compare it with current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because

```
 dtCurrentTimePlus15 = 15
```

and

```
dtLastLoginAttempt = 2
```

Invert the statement to:

```
if ((iLoginAttempts > 4) && (dtLastLoginAttempt < dtCurrentTimePlus15))
{
    oCust.CustLoginStatus = "Your account is currently locked.";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I knew it had to be fairly easy. Thanks @Leniel

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a logical `or`, not an AND. You will only lock someone out if they've met both of those conditions: more than 4 attemps AND less than the timeout period.

With an `or`, you'll lock out anyone meets ONE or BOTH of those two conditions.